# what Win32 funcntion does WaitOneCore call internally?

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr

when I read the source code of `WaitHandle` https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/WaitHandle.CoreCLR.cs,1

```
public abstract partial class WaitHandle
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    private static extern int WaitOneCore(IntPtr waitHandle, int millisecondsTimeout, bool useTrivialWaits);  // calls WaitForSingleObjectEx?

    // ...
}
```

I am curious what Win32 fucntion (I guess it is `WaitForSingleObjectEx`) does `WaitOneCore` called internally, but how can I verify it? I checked the source code on Microsoft offical Github repo, didn't find anything. What C++ repo (CLR is written by C++) do I need to check ?

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET? The .NET version has this for Windows: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/WaitHandle.Windows.cs. Should be using WaitForMultipleObjectsEx but passing in 1 handle.

Comment: Internal calls are implemented in the runtime in C++ https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fruntime%20CorWaitOneNative&type=code (note github.com/dotnet/corert was deprecated a long time ago)